# How to modify CMakeList.txt: library found, but there are linking errors

Tags: c, cmake, clang, linker-errors

I am creating a C library which is to be built with cmake, using Mac OS for development. In the CMakeList.txt, I have the following

```
#htslib
find_package(htslib REQUIRED)
include_directories(${HTSLIB_INCLUDE_DIR})


target_link_libraries(projectname ${HTSlib_LIBRARIES})
```

which outputs upon `cmake ..`

```
Found hstlib
```

However, upon `make`, I'm getting linker errors:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So...it can find the library, and the library is definitely installed with `sudo make install`, but there are linking errors only with this library.

(1) I'm guessing that `find_package(htslib REQUIRED)` is finding something else. How do I find out what?

(2) How do I explicitly write in CMakeList.txt to find the library which I know has been installed correctly?

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html). `find_package` has a lot of option which which you can control where it looks for packages. The documentation say that the full path of the package configuration is stored in `<package>_CONFIG`, so print that variable to see which file is being loaded by cmake.

Comment: Also when a package adds a library, let's say `XYZ`, you have add that to your project with [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html): `target_link_libraries(porject_awesome htslib)`

Comment: @Pablo Thanks for the help. Trying to `MESSAGE()` htslib_CONFIG gives me nothing it appears. However, doing the same for `htslib_LIBRARIES` shows me that `libhts.dylib` exists in `/usr/local/lib/`

Comment: @Pablo I should have made it clear that I'm using `target_link_libraries(porject_awesome htslib)`  above. Apologies.

Comment: Strange, I created a dummy cmake project and added `find_package(PNG)`. There is no variable `PNG_CONFIG`. Unless there's something in the documentation I missed, I don't know why it's empty.

Comment: @Pablo You're saying it's a documentation error?

Comment: I don't know, I cannot find any example where someone uses that. Anyway, you can call `cmake` with `--trace` option. This will print the files that `cmake` opens. In my example, `cd build; cmake --trace ..` tells me that `find_package(PNG)` opens the file `/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPNG.cmake`. Execute your `cmake` with `--trace` to see which file is reading for your package. You might also want to post that file here in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `VERBOSE=1 make` to see the linker output. Search for `-lhtslib`
2. Read the documentation for the specific `Find<LIB>.cmake`.

Your specific questions:

1. "How do I find what CMake found": Use `cmake-gui` or `ccmake`. They both show the same info, but one is a GUI and the other is a Curses interface. In the advanced mode ("t" on `ccmake`) you will find all the variables for the searched packages. Additionally, you may use `MESSAGE(STATUS "Found htslib at: ${htslib_LIBRARIES}")`.
2. "How to explicitly write in CMakeLists.txt where the library is?" Please, do not do that! CMake is meant for abstracting exactly this kind of information away. You have two options, first the good one: configure cmake on the command line (or in the GUIs mentioned above) to get a `CMAKE_MODULES_PATH` or a more specific hint to the library `-D htslib_PATH=/usr/local/.../` (pointing to the dir where `libhts.dylib` resides). The worse solution would be to provide a HINT to `find_package`. `find_package(htslib REQUIRED PATH /usr/local/lib)` or `find_package(htslib REQUIRED HINT /usr/local/lib /some/second/path/where/it/may/be)`.

## Solution

Your linked project has a custom `FindHTSlib.cmake` [link](https://github.com/D-Lo/bamdb/blob/master/cmake/FindHTSlib.cmake). This one uses `pkg_config` to configure the library. To replicate your problem, I used **brew** to install `htslib`. The pkg-config file can be found (for me, but `brew info htslib` tells you) under `/usr/local/Cellar/htslib/1.8/lib/htslib.pc`. So, let's give CMake the required hint.

I couldn't test this, because for me it found the htslib package directly with no further hints.

```
git clone https://github.com/D-Lo/bamdb # I am using version f5f03d0
mkdir -p bamdb/build; cd bamdb/build
brew install ck htslib lmdb
cmake ..  # -G Ninja recommended, but needs brew install ninja
make # lot's of missing symbols
```

I would recommend to change in `CMakeLists.txt` the minimum required version of CMake from 2.8 to `3.10` (or at least 3.6).

This is the error I get:

```
[ 62%] Linking C shared library libbamdb.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.1/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/libbamdb.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -Wall -g -std=gnu99 -fPIC -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  -o libbamdb.dylib -install_name @rpath/libbamdb.dylib CMakeFiles/libbamdb.dir/src/bam_api.c.o CMakeFiles/libbamdb.dir/src/bam_lmdb.c.o CMakeFiles/libbamdb.dir/src/bamdb.c.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_bam_destroy1", referenced from:
      _get_bam_row in bam_api.c.o
      _deserialize_func in bam_lmdb.c.o
```

This can be fixed by adding the following line in the `CMakeLists.txt`, after the line `add_library(libbamdb ${SOURCES})`:

```
target_link_libraries(libbamdb ${LIBS})
```

Some further notes: you now have a library with a `main` function. This is because `${SOURCES}` is used to build the executable and the library. That can have unexpected side effects. Unless it's needed, don't do it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed help! This is much appreciated, and very helpful for users (especially me) to learn

Comment: "I would recommend to change in CMakeLists.txt the minimum required version of CMake from 2.8 to 3.10 (or at least 3.6)." This is a good idea. Is there a reason you say 3.6?

Comment: Sorry, I just now realised the actual problem in your original question: You are using `${HTSlib_LIBRARIES}`, but the linked FindHTSlib.cmake only exports  `HTSlib_LIBRARY`. So, use that and you would've been fine.

Comment: I was recommending CMake 3.6 because I remember that some bugs have been fixed there as opposed to version 3.2. However, I don't know exactly which bugs this was. You could also choose 3.5.1 because that is widely used in Ubuntu 16.04. Just avoid 2.8!

Comment: I just tested both. Using `HTSlib_LIBRARY` in `set(LIBS ...)` fails with the linking error. Adding `target_link_libraries(libbamdb ${LIBS})` after `add_library(libbamdb SHARED ${SOURCES})` with `HTSlib_LIBRARIES` works!

Comment: "Sorry, I just now realised the actual problem in your original question" So, I think this somehow isn't correct, as I detailed in the earlier comment. I've yet to figure out why...